# Red shift/blue shift: how would it appear to a fast-moving observer?

Tags: special-relativity

I've read sci-fi stories in which a spaceship crew, moving at some significant fraction of 'c', observes stars ahead as bluer, stars behind as redder, stars to port and starboard as...well, you get the idea.

This seems wrong, though I'm not sure if it is. Seems to me the red/blue shifts would only be apparent with spectroscopic analysis, not to the naked eye. Yes? No?

Comment: It depends on the speed involved.  Very distant galaxies, whose light is strongly redshifted before it reaches us, may have ultraviolet atomic transitions that reach us in the infrared.

Comment: Still (as far as I know), it takes an analysis of spectrum lines to determine how fast distant galaxies are receding. Even if our science-fictional crew were travelling at, say, .99 'c', objects behind would have their blues shifted toward the red, while objects ahead would have their reds shifted toward the blue, and so on. Because of this shift, it seems to me everything would look the same in every direction, at least to the naked eye.

Comment: Not true: the broadband visible and ultraviolet radiation from stars in those galaxies is also shifted to the infrared.

Comment: That was more or less my point. We know the speed of light is constant regardless of the observer's velocity, but if the same were true of wavelength, astronomers and astrophysicists could in theory determine speed of recession by simply looking at true-color images, supposing any such were available. The entire spectrum is shifted, which to me suggests that receding (and invisible) ultraviolet would appear as visible violet, while advancing (and likewise invisible) infrared as visible red. In other words, the universe all around would still look pretty much the same.

Comment: Not at all: the universe in infrared and the universe in ultraviolet are quite different from each other and from the universe in the visible.

Comment: Indeed they are, but wouldn't e.g. gamma rays, if red-shifted far enough by relative velocity, reveal the same picture of the universe as X-rays? Or, conversely, wouldn't microwave radiation, if blue-shifted far enough by relative velocity, reveal the same picture as infrared? I'm not arguing the point, only trying to understand...

Comment: No.  Radio, microwave, infrared, visible, ultraviolet, x-ray, and gamma-ray photons all arise from distinct physical processes taking place at different energy scales and are bright and dim in different parts of the sky.  Compare the five full-sky images [here](http://www.spacehike.com/multiwavelength.html): there's definitely always a galaxy, but it's different.

Answer (score 1):

Stars, and by extension galaxies, are approximately black body emitters so the light from then shows a black body spectrum. For example the light from the Sun has a spectrum corresponding (approximately) to a black body with a temperature of about 5,700K.

[image: Solar spectrum]
(picture from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight))

So sunlight peaks in intensity around 500-600nm and as a result looks slightly yellow. At a red or blue shift of 2 the peak would be in the infrared or ultraviolet respectively and the colour of the sunlight would change accordingly.